# How can i do a comparison in Groovy script?

Tags: groovy

I am comparing values in Groovy as follows:

```
 if (creds.username == env.Username  && creds.password == env.Password)
 {       
       foundUser  = true;
       break;       
 }
```

It should return foundUser = true , but the issue is the second comparison, ( creds.password == env.Password ) if I take that out it works .
Any ideas as to why this may happen ?

Comment: They are different?

Comment: No when i print the values out  creds.password = "testpwd" and  env.Password = "testpwd"

Comment: Sure there's not an extra space or something?

Comment: Try `println creds.password.bytes` and compare it to the other one

Comment: I wil try that , was thinking i may need to trim

Comment: creds.password could be not a string. try to println creds.password.getClass()

Comment: it is a class hudson.util.Secret. Can i print that out ?

Comment: I just added creds.password.getPlainText(), seems to work